# How to get similar character in php and regex?

Tags: php, regex

```
<?php
    $a="eye";
    $c=array("yep", "eye", "yee", "eey", "ded", "sfsf");
    $arrlength=count($c);

    for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++) {
      echo $c[$x];
      echo "<br>";
    }

?>
```

I want to get the similar values from a list . How can i do this?
Example: My variable is eye
and i want the all words having letters `"e","y","e"` from following array

```
array("eye", "abcd", "yee", "hello");
```

How can i get this in php and regex?

Comment: You mean `in_array()` ?  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php . If not, what is your expected output from your above example ?

Comment: Can you show us the desired output according to the array you already have?

Comment: i want same letters from that array. its ans will be eye, yee, yep, eey

Comment: So you want only the anagrams?

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = str_split($a);

foreach ($c as $word) {
    $array2 = str_split($word);

    // if all characters in $array2 are present in $array1
    $subset = count(array_intersect($array2, $array1)) == count($array1);

    if ($subset && strlen($word) <= strlen($a)) {
        echo $word . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
eye
yee
eey
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/83314)

Comment: @user3137291: Not working isn't very descriptive. What exactly isn't working? Do you get any errors? What happens when you try the code?

Comment: @user3137291: Here's a demo: https://eval.in/83298

Comment: but if i am taking array this one

Comment: $c=array("yep","eye","yee","eey","ded","sfsf","fare","farer","sfjshsfkj","eeye");
then its also showing eeye

Comment: @user3137291: In that case, simply add an `strlen()` check. See demo: https://eval.in/83302

Comment: its output should not be yep

Comment: @user3137291: Ah. I've updated the answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare regexp

```
$temp = str_split($a);
$regexp="/".implode("|", $temp)."/i";
```

then use this regexp in  foreach

```
foreach($c AS $str) {
  echo $str;
  if (preg_match($regexp, $str) {
    echo "yes";
  } else {
    echo "no";
  }
  echo "<br />"
}
```

I don't test code, but I hope you can understand main idea